# WELD-001335: Ambiguous dependencies for type Ref<HttpServletRequest>

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jax-rs, cdi

I would like to obtain the remote address of a client calling my web service. I am trying to gain access to HttpServletRequest, but the ambiguous dependencies exception is thrown when a client calls the service.

Dependencies were automatically added by IntelliJ and I will admit to being a novice when it comes to tracking down issues in code that I did not write! My endpoint code, the stack trace and POM follow.

I have been hacking away at this for a couple of days now, so any help greatly appreciated!!

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

@Path("/visitor")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Visitors {

    @POST
    @Path("/web")
    public Response identify(@Context HttpServletRequest req, Visit visit) {

        String remoteAddr = req.getRemoteAddr();
        ...
```

Trace:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [vv.vvApplication] in context with path [/vv_war_exploded] threw exception [org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001335: Ambiguous dependencies for type Ref<HttpServletRequest> with qualifiers @Default
 Possible dependencies: 
  - org.glassfish.jersey.inject.cdi.se.bean.SupplierInstanceBeanBridge@730f19db,
  - org.glassfish.jersey.inject.cdi.se.bean.SupplierInstanceBeanBridge@62233485] with root cause
    org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001335: Ambiguous dependencies for type Ref<HttpServletRequest> with qualifiers @Default
 Possible dependencies: 
  - org.glassfish.jersey.inject.cdi.se.bean.SupplierInstanceBeanBridge@730f19db,
  - org.glassfish.jersey.inject.cdi.se.bean.SupplierInstanceBeanBridge@62233485
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.checkBeanResolved(InstanceImpl.java:244)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:113)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ReferencingFactory.get(ReferencingFactory.java:69)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.cdi.se.bean.SupplierBeanBridge.create(SupplierBeanBridge.java:110)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.cdi.se.injector.ContextInjectionResolverImpl.resolve(ContextInjectionResolverImpl.java:76)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.lambda$getValueProvider$0(DelegatedInjectionValueParamProvider.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.apply(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:50)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:64)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
...
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>vv</groupId>
    <artifactId>vv</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>vv</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- MySQL Dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL Dependencies -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.35</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-reload4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-reload4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.35</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->

        <!-- StringUtils -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SHA256 Hashing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-cdi2-se</artifactId>
            <version>2.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for LocalDateTime object mapping-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```